# How to reduce the space between the td in table html?

Tags: html, css

I design a table like the below. I need to avoid the space between username and it's textbox like as password and it's textbox. Please tell me how to do this?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      UserName
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:left">
      <input id="userName" type="text" value="" placeholder="UserName" />   
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      password
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:left">
      <input id="password" type="text" value="" placeholder="password" />   
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left">
      <input  id="btnsearch" type="button" value="Search" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Some extra space is between username and textbox and same as password and pwd textbox. How to reduce the space between them please tell me.

Comment: can you add your css..

Comment: Any acceptable answer so far? Nothing helpful for you?

Answer (score 4):

The [table element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) can be attributed with a border width, cellpadding and cellspacing.

[image]

So you can create a table like so (where units a numerals without lenght, means NOT 2px but 2) :

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

**List of a TABLE's attributes**:
summary %Text; width %Length; border %Pixels; frame %TFrame; rules %TRules; cellspacing %Length; cellpadding %Length;

But with recent web design techniques, it is recommended to separate html markups from layout and design element. To achieve this, you will have to use css.

You can achieve the same like so :

```
table {border-spacing:0;border-width:0;}
table td {padding:2px;border-width:0;}
```

With css, you will also have to specify if the borders are going to be collapsed or separated, witch will have effect on 'border-spacing'.

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

To avoid some legacy browswers bugs, i invite you to NOT leave an empty space before the closing  `</td>` like : `<input  id="btnsearch" type="button" value="Search"/></td>` (but this is to become outdated except if you develop for old-timers)

To conclude with your situation :

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:0 none;}
/* fix padding of TD to suit your needs */
table td {border:0 none;padding:2px;text-align:left;}
```

and you will be able to format your table the simpliest way :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i addded above attributes.but width of td may be need to reduce.i didn't menstion any width of td default based on content size it's taking width of td.there is no space between two td's but width of td is problem.

Comment: @user3106578 width of which cell is problem for you?

Comment: i given button colspan as 2 and text-align as center but it looks some what more of the alignment of center.pls tell how to exaactly arrange the button in center.

Answer (score 1):

The cellSpacing, cellPadding and border can help you accomplish that:

```
   <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left">
                  UserName<br/>
                 <input id="userName" type="text" value=""  placeholder="UserName"/>   
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left">
                 password<br/>
                 <input id="password" type="text" value=""  placeholder="password"/>   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left">
             <input  id="btnsearch" type="button" value="Search"/>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

If you need them tightly close put them on the same td and perform the line break through a `<br/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Add few attributes in your table tag like

```
<table cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0'>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D58Fs/4/)**

**Edited Part:**

```
<table cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0'  border="0" >
```

## **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D58Fs/5/)**

To know more about CellSpacing & CellPadding [**Click Here**](http://www.htmlite.com/lite012b.php)

[image: Cell Spacing & Cell Padding]